# python ,infinite random sentence generator of specified length

Tags: python, generator

I have a dictionary

```
{
    'went': ['up', 'up'],
    'water': ['spout'],
    'all': ['the'],
    'again': [],
    'up': ['the', 'all', 'the'],
    'spider': ['went', 'out', 'went']
}
```

... created from a text file(filename)

Based on this dictionary I have to create infinite random sentences of specified length. It will start with a random word in the dictionary (a key), then pick another random word from the list of words that come after it, then pick another random word from the list of words that come after the second word and so on until it has the required number of words. It will then yield all these words as a sentence.

```
def sentence_generator(filename, length=10):
     """
     Makes up random sentences based on that dictionary.

     Parameters: a filename that refers to a text file to 'imitate',
                 a length that will be the number of words in the generated
                 sentence.  If omitted the length will default to 10.
     """
     random.seed(1) # set the seed for the random generator

     my_dict1 = learn(filename)
     while True:
         for key, value in my_dict1.items(): 
             my_list = my_dict1.values()
             yield my_dict1[key]
             random.choice(sorted(my_list))
```

I need to know how to use the 'length' in the function. I am not sure how

Comment: I have a sense of what you are trying to do here, but I don't see `'the'` or `'out'` as keys in the dictionary. What happens if that is the word we pick from the list?

Comment: Is this the whole function? Where is the part where it outputs the sentence?

Comment: This is my attempted function. My output at the prompt ..Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:44:40) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>>> from language import sentence_generator
>>> baby = sentence_generator('spider.txt', 5)
>>> next(baby)
['the', 'itsy', 'down', 'out', 'and']
>>> next(baby)
['came', 'the']
>>> next(baby)
['spout']

Comment: What do you mean by `lenght`?

Comment: def sentence_generator(filename, length=10):  Length is the parameter and the random sentences outputted should have the specified length of words for ex:  baby = sentence_generator('spider.txt', 5) where length is 5

Comment: This is all wrong.  You aren't conditioning you choice on the word you picked.  You're always choosing from my_dict1.values(), but you should be choosing from my_dict1[key] where `key` is the last word selected.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write a generator that `yield`s `length` words. So you could change your the  `while` loop to count the number of words produced and stop after `length` words.